# Nullpointer with navigation drawer

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to get put data to my list view in slide menu application using navigation drawer. I created a list view and defined the adapter but when i run it i got null pointer in the logcat

here is my codes:

```
package chnt.appchef.com;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   String[] menu;
   DrawerLayout dLayout;
   ListView dList;
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

   String[] countryArray = {"India", "Pakistan", "USA", "UK"};

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
          R.layout.activity_listview, countryArray);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Raspberry Pi","WordPress","Videos","Contact Us"};
      dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
      dList.setAdapter(adapter);
  dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
      dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
      dLayout.closeDrawers();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
      Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
      detail.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
    }
      });
  }
}
```

and this is detail fragment class

```
package chnt.appchef.com;
  import android.app.Fragment;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
TextView text;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_detail_fragment, container, false);
    String menu = getArguments().getString("Menu");
    text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
    text.setText(menu);
    return view;
}
  }
```

and i defined the list view as well

**logcat**

```
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chnt.appchef.com/chnt.appchef.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at chnt.appchef.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
12-26 16:12:57.796: E/AndroidRuntime(19145):    ... 11 more
12-26 16:13:00.066: I/Process(19145): Sending signal. PID: 19145 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is line no 31 in `MainActivity`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and initializing instance adapter1 but assigning instance adapter to listview which is yet not initialized and is null.

so change

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are creating adapter1 and assign adapter. look at here:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
          R.layout.activity_listview, countryArray);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

change this:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change listview.setAdapter(adapter) to listview.setAdapter(adapter1)